# Load url in headless browser to get its dynamic content using node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, puppeteer

I have node js application with single home page. This home page will dynamically render the content using API.

To increase performance, I dont want to call every time when user launch the url and make API call to render content. Instead i want to create the static file with HTML content and store in folder and render when user the launch the url.

To achieve this, First i need headless browser to load url and get HTML content and put the content into file and store as unique HTML file(Fi2FEt1gM.html)under folder using node JS

I am trying to get Dynamic HTML content as shown below

Approach 1:

> ```
>             var http = require("http");
>
>                 http.get('http://localhost:3001/Fi2FEt1gM', function(res){
>                     res.setEncoding('utf8');
>                     res.on('data', function(chunk){
>                         console.log(chunk);
>                     });
>                 });
> ```

Approach 2:

> ```
>             const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
>
>               (async () => {
>                 try {
>                   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
>                   const page = await browser.newPage();
>                   await page.goto('http://localhost:3001/Fi2FEt1gM');
>                   await page.waitForSelector('html', { timeout: 3000 });
>
>                   const body = await page.evaluate(() => {
>                     return document.querySelector('body').innerHTML;
>                   });
>                   console.log(body);
>
>                   await browser.close();
>                 } catch (error) {
>                   console.log(error);
>                 }
>               })();
> ```

From all approach, I always get static HTML not dynamic content. My scrape content will be like below

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
>     <meta name="author" content="">
>     ....
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div class='wrapper'>
>         <div class="container">
>             Loading...
>             <-- DYNAMIC CONTENT --->
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Please advise on my approach

Comment: Is the dynamic content served from your server or from a remote server?

Comment: aksappy, dynamic content served from same server!

Comment: So you need a single fixed endpoint, that serves dynamic content. And in your puppeteer calls you need to call the fixed endpoint that serves dynamic content, get the content, write to a new file. Is that how it is now?

Comment: My page will have change of visit more than million visitors. To avoid frequent call and increase performance i had thought of generate HTML file under one folder and use that generated file to render when user launch the page. This would help in performance. Yes your understanding is right

Comment: Well, if the content really does not change according to who accesses it at what time, and you are okay with the small time where the switch happens this should fare well. Hopefully, you will not start scaling up with multiple servers, in which case this will be a little tough.

Comment: For each url will have different content respectively ... Dynamically content Wil change based on url code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214956/discussion-between-mymotherland-and-aksappy).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this work for you?

wget -q --mirror -p --adjust-extension -e robots=off --base=./ -k -P ./ [yoururl]

This should result in static pages you can then parse the way you want.